# How do you combine multiple JSON strings into one ( Java )

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I tried searching for a JAVA library that I could use but to no avail.
Is there a gson/jackson/groovy library I could use to combine or merge together multiple JSON Strings into one payload?

Example :
JSON payload A, B and C

I would like both B and C to be added/merged to A.

Also removing any duplicated keys that are null or empty.

Example :

1. First JSON :

```
{
   "businessUnitHierarchies":[
      {
         "actionType":"sample123",
         "businessUnitHierarchy":{
            "businessUnit":"sample123"
         }
      }
   ],
   "description":{
      "EN":"description sample",
      "FR":"sample de description"
   },
   "name":{
      "EN":"Coupon by a bot",
      "FR":"Coupon par un bot"
   },
   "discountType":"Cost+",
   "quantity":0,
   "usageType":"shared",
   "notes":"sample notes",
   "discounts":[
      {
         "discountLevel":"SAMPLE",
         "discountAmount":"10"
      }
   ],
   "couponId":0
}
```

2. Second JSON :

```
    {
       "effectiveDate":"2020-09-10",
       "expiryDate":"2020-09-11",
       "quantity":0,
       "couponId":0
    }
```

3. Third JSON

```
    {
   "productHierarchies":[
      {
         "productHierarchy":{
            "level":7
         },
         "businessUnit":"fgl",
         "actionType":"include",
         "brand":"SAMPLE",
         "discountAmount":"35"
      }
   ],
   "quantity":0,
   "couponId":0
}
```

My desired output is :

Desired Output :

```
{
   "businessUnitHierarchies":[
      {
         "actionType":"sample123",
         "businessUnitHierarchy":{
            "businessUnit":"sample123"
         }
      }
   ],
   "description":{
      "EN":"description sample",
      "FR":"sample de description"
   },
   "name":{
      "EN":"Coupon by a bot",
      "FR":"Coupon par un bot"
   },
   "discountType":"Cost+",
   "quantity":0,
   "usageType":"shared",
   "notes":"sample notes",
   "discounts":[
      {
         "discountLevel":"SAMPLE",
         "discountAmount":"10"
      }
   ],
   "couponId":0,
      "effectiveDate":"2020-09-10",
   "expiryDate":"2020-09-11",
   "quantity":0,
   "productHierarchies":[
      {
         "productHierarchy":{
            "level":7
         },
         "businessUnit":"fgl",
         "actionType":"include",
         "brand":"SAMPLE",
         "discountAmount":"35"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why not parse the JSONs to Java objects, use composition to add objects to the container class (A) and then format back to JSON. This should require nothing more than basic Java and JSON parsing.

Comment: If all you needed was to join the strings it wouldn't be a problem, but you are applying specific business logic to the merge.  That is going to require coding for your specific scenario, even if you did find some library to do this it would probably take longer to figure out how to use the library and build the ruleset then it would be to just create the 4 java objects and do the merge yourself.  There are lots of "quick fixes" but sometimes you just have to buckle down and write custom code.  Use a json to Java object creator to quickly build the classes needed.  Google "json to java".

Comment: your result JSON is **NOT** valid, because there cannot be a duplicate key "quantity" in one JSON object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be all you want? Based on [Gson](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html).

```java
void merge(JsonObject dest, JsonObject src) {
    for (var entry : src.entrySet()) {
        dest.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue();
    }
}
```